# What is the basic difference between absolute pressure and gauge pressure?

Tags: pressure

What is the basic difference between absolute pressure and gauge pressure?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20460/2451

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia :

**Absolute pressure** is zero-referenced against a perfect vacuum, so it is equal to gauge pressure plus atmospheric pressure.

**Gauge pressure** is zero-referenced against ambient air pressure, so it is equal to absolute pressure minus atmospheric pressure. Negative signs are usually omitted. To distinguish a negative pressure, the value may be appended with the word "vacuum" or the gauge may be labeled a "vacuum gauge."

So suppose you are in an ocean at height depth,your absolute pressure would be $Patm+\rho*g*d$ while your guage pressure would be simply $\rho*g*d$, also you can say if at any point your total pressure is P your absolute pressure is $P$ while your guage pressure is $P - Patm$