# Why can I feel the air inside the pump pressing against my finger when it is at 1 bar (atmospheric pressure)?

Tags: pressure

Atmospheric pressure is approximately 1 bar, but when I cover my bike pump with my finger and increase the pressure to 1 bar I can feel it pushing my finger away - how come?

I'm guessing that what bike pumps call 1 bar is actually 1 bar above atmospheric pressure - otherwise they it should read 1 bar to begin with, right?

I am disappointed that as a 4th year physicist I can't figure this out...

Comment: May or may not be relevant here, but 1 atm and 1 bar are not exactly equal.

Comment: Yes, the pressure in your pump is 2 bar.

Comment: Related: [Gauge pressure vs. absolute pressure?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/gauge-pressure-vs-absolute-pressure)